# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, javafx-8

I've got stuck and can't help myself. 
My project structure looks like this:

- InvalidQuizFormatException.java
- Quiz_GUI.java
- QuizMaker.java

In `QuizMaker` I want to create a new instance of a `Quiz_GUI` javafx class, where in testing purposes wanted to start a quiz. However, when I compile everything I get an error:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: InvalidQuizFormatException    at
>   QuizMaker.lambda$start$0(QuizMaker.java:35)

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


public class Quiz_GUI extends Pane {
    private String fileName;


   public Quiz_GUI(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        startQuiz();
   }


   private void startQuiz() {

        try {
            Quiz newQuiz;
            newQuiz = Quiz.loadFromFile(this.fileName);
            newQuiz.start();
        } catch (InvalidQuizFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Inside a `QuizMaker` I have:

```
Quiz_GUI myQuiz = new Quiz_GUI(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `InvalidQuizFormatException` for `Exception` and it will work as this is the default exception class.

Comment: My pleasure @Kas!

Comment: Catching java.lang.Exception is a bad practice (it hides programmer errors like NullPointerExceptions), and this does not address the cause of the problem at all.

Comment: Agree! However an opinion isn't debugging unfortunately. From there, I would suggest him to contact the team and ask them where they want to go with it. However, I think SO hasn't been built for that reason. Again, it is my opinion.